# OpenGL: Perspective matrix shows nothing

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, matrix

I am doing some basic OpenGL with Qt in order to try and get some simple geometry to render. I've created a cube between `(-1,-1,-1)` and `(1,1,1)` and rotated it so that the overall shape is recognisable, and I can see it if I use an orthographic projection matrix:

```
QMatrix4x4 orthographicMatrix(float top, float bottom, float left, float right, float near, float far)
{
    return QMatrix4x4((2.0f)/(right-left), 0, 0, -(right+left)/(right-left),
                      0, (2.0f)/(top-bottom), 0, -(top+bottom)/(top-bottom),
                      0, 0, -(2.0f)/(far-near), -(far+near)/(far-near),
                      0, 0, 0, 1);
}

...

QMatrix4x4 Projection = orthographicMatrix(2, -2, 2, -2, 0.01f, 2);
```

The formula for generating orthographic/projection matrices is taken from https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/22/opengl-101-matrices-projection-view-model/

This matrix allows me to see the cube if I translate the camera to 1 on Z:

[image: Cube is visible]

However, if I use a perspective matrix (again using the formula from the linked page):

```
QMatrix4x4 perspectiveMatrix(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far)
{
    float top = near * qTan((M_PI/180.0f) * (fov/2.0f));
    float bottom = -top;
    float right = top * aspectRatio;
    float left = -right;

    return QMatrix4x4((2.0f-near)/(right-left), 0, (right+left)/(right-left), 0,
                      0, (2.0f-near)/(top-bottom), (top+bottom)/(top-bottom), 0,
                      0, 0, -(far+near)/(far-near), -(2.0f-far-near)/(far-near),
                      0, 0, -1, 0);
}

...

QMatrix4x4 Projection = perspectiveMatrix(60.0f, (float)width()/(float)height(), 0.01f, 2);
```

I get no geometry displaying at all from the same camera position:

[image: No geometry showing.]

I've checked the code many times and can't work out why nothing shows up. I gather it must be something to do with the perspective matrix but my code seems to follow exactly what is specified on the Solarian Programmer page. What could be wrong here?

For reference, my shaders are:

```
// Vertex
#version 330 core
in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
uniform mat4 MVP;
void main()
{
    vec4 v = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
    gl_Position = MVP * v;
}

// Fragment
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
float remap(float inp)
{
    while (inp>200.0) inp-=200.0;
    return inp/200.0;
}

void main()
{
    color = vec3(remap(gl_FragCoord.x), remap(gl_FragCoord.y), 0);
}
```

Comment: To debug an issue like this make a test project with a math library known to be correct like glm and compare its result for the same input parameters to your own (::perspective matrix).  Then you can at least rule that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you made some mistakes by implementing the perspective matrix from the reference.

For example, the first entry is `(2.0f-near)/(right-left)` in your code while it is `(2.0f * near)/(right-left)` on the website. Similar errors are also in other fields of the matrix.

Comment: Apparently I'm not used to working with a retina screen! That was the problem and replacing the erroneous minuses with multiplications seems to work. Thanks!